# Change style prop NaviagtionBar @shoutem/ui

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, shoutem

I try to add shoutem to other app but when i work with NaviagtionBar and @shoutem/animation i got issue like picture below here:
[image]

this i got when using props style NavigationBar 'inline',
and here is my code:

```js
 <NavigationBar
                        styleName="inline"
                        animationName="solidify"
                        title={restaurant.name}
                        share={{
                            title: restaurant.name,
                            link: restaurant.url,
                        }}
                    />
```

but i dont want like that. I want props style is 'clear' for make tranparent navigationbar when start app, i still want show it when scroll down like this:
[image]
but when i change props style of NavigationBar to 'clear' i got this issue(when scroll down, NavigationBar still not show up):
[image]
Anyone can help me to resolve it?

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e) and try to reproduce it. That's pretty much the exact animation you're looking for, just changing from an image to a single color.

Comment: Ty so much man! I will try it